# In which directory do I find a specific HTML code of my wordpress page? Some of it seems to be missing after checking all pages

Tags: themes, html, server, ftp

So I would like to access this part of the HTML and be able to edit it (see image below)

[image: Retrieved from the Inspect Element]

However when I access my ftp server and navigate to the *Footer.php* section, this part of the HTML is not to be found. I also checked *Header.php* and all other files in the **wp-content/themes/mytheme** but to no avail. Refer to image below. So where can I locate 'menu-image-title' please? Thanks in advance.

[image: Unable to locate menu-image-title tag]

Answer (score 3):

The code you are referring to is a menu, and in your screenshot, is likely to be the line starting `wp_nav_menu`...

Look in your WP admin under Appearance > Menus, and you should have a Social Media Links menu it seems...

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress fonctions sometimes generates classes that are not visible in your files.
Instead search class name it can be helpful to serach html tags or write directly a few words in your page, then push it via FTP an localte it in your site. sometimes it's because your are not targeting the right file.

Answer (score 0):

this html does not appear in a directory like you are looking for.  This code is generated dynamically by the php code using values that you have put into the database via the also php-generated pages/fields.

If you want to modify the code you need to modify the php that generates the code